# Default implementation for generic method

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a `trait Foo`

Also I have a trait that uses trait Foo in type parameter

```
trait Bar[T <: Foo] {
 def bar: T = new Foo {} //doesn't compile
}
```

I want to provide default implementaition in trait `Bar` for `bar` method. I need this because there are several implementations that do not need to override `bar` method(they are just happy with `Foo`), but also there are some implemenations that do need to provide specific implemetaions of `Foo` in `bar` method.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please include the compiler error message.

Comment: The reason it doesn't compile is that `T <: Foo` means that `T` will be potentially be a subtype of `Foo`.  In the event that the `Bar` type is constructed with a subtype of `Foo`, your default implementation will return a supertype of `T`.  This is akin to having a method which returns a `String` and returning `new Object()`.  I think to further help you, we will need a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: You could just have a `trait FooBar extends Bar[Foo]` that provides this implementation.

Comment: @joescii  Suppose I have 100 possible implentation of Bar. and in 70 of them T == Foo. I don't want to repeat code(`new Foo{}`) in 70 cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon the suggestion from @TravisBrown, you can have your `Bar` trait:

```
trait Bar[T <: Foo] {
  def bar: T
}
```

And another trait to provide your default:

```
trait FooBar extends Bar[Foo] {
  def bar = new Foo {}
}
```

Then all of your implementations which don't need specialization can extend `FooBar` rather than `Bar`

```
class Baz extends FooBar {
  // Compiles without a def bar:T implementation
}
```